# Receber mais de um valor por linha com C

Tags: c, matriz, scanf

Eu preciso fazer um código em que é necessário receber mais de um valor por linha, porém eu não sei quantos valores serão

A ideia inicial seria usar

```
scanf("%d", valor);
```

Porém, nesse caso eu só estaria recebendo um valor, e pode ser 1, 2, 3, 4...

Na verdade, o usuário vai me dar as dimensões de uma matriz e seus números, eu preciso ler um número de cada vez, porém tudo vai ser "entregue" na mesma linha, por exemplo:

1 2 3

 5 3 1

 4 4 1

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Mas quantos números são no total ? Como sabe quando deve parar ?

Comment: O `scanf` consegue ler mais de um valor por linha, já que ele não consome a quebra de linha se não achar necessário. Então bastaria chamar várias vezes em um *loop*, mas de qualquer forma ainda não está claro qual o critério de parada

Comment: no começo ele vai dar a quantidade de colunas, portanto se são 4 colunas seriam 4 números

Comment: Então eu sugiro [edit] a pergunta e colocar todos esses detalhes no texto. Assim as pessoas não precisam "caçar" informações nos comentários. Mas enfim, se vc tem a quantidade, basta usar um laço e ir lendo...

Answer (score 2):

Tem muitas maneiras de ler isso mas acho que sempre é chato.

Como a matriz é de `int` ajuda um pouco, e vou te mostrar uma maneira.

### A lógica

Se você não soubesse quantas colunas são até o cara digitar a linha toda e teclar ENTER então teria que contar os campos e ver quantos foram na primeira linha.

A partir daí saberia quantas colunas foram e nas próximas linhas estaria resolvido.

Para contar os campos pode ler a linha toda com `fgets()`, o simples porque aí não precisa se preocupar com mais nada.

#### Exemplo

Se você ler a linha com `fgets(linha,sizeof(linha),stdin);` esse loop

```
        char* p    = linha;
        char* next = NULL;
        unsigned nc = 0;
        printf("\n\nLinha: \"%s\"\n", teste[t]);
        while ((*p != 0))
        {
            long numero = strtol(p, &next, 10); 
            if ((next - p) == 0) break;
            p = next;
            printf("%ld  ", numero);
            nc += 1;
        }  // uma coluna
        printf("\nLeu %u campos nessa linha\n", nc);
```

vai ler os campos 1 a 1 em `numero` e contar em `nc` quantos são.

**Vou deixar um exemplo mais completo a seguir**.

A diferença de ler com `strtol()` ao invés de `scanf()` é que no primeiro caso a função foi escrita com isso em mente: `strtol()` pode retornar um ponteiro para a string indicando até onde ela foi consumida e assim você pode percorrer a string sem testar os índices e procurar os espaços e tal.

`scanf()` e outras funções da família, como `sscanf()`, por outro lado, foram escritas para consumir dados tabulares e não "andam" pela linha a menos que esteja lendo um arquivo. Mas `scanf()` trata *espaço*, *TAB* e *newline* como genérico *whitespace* e você não consegue saber se a linha terminou ao ler um campo porque a função passa reto: tudo é *whitespace* e não consegue distinguir o `newline`. Apenas com `fscanf()` e quando tem um delimitador, tipo um arquivo *csv*, se pode usar isso e ler com facilidade, porque pode testar se o campo terminou com o delimitador ou com o *newline*, mas não é o caso aqui: o tal delimitador não pode ser *whitespace*: nem `TAB` nem espaço. Pode ser `newline` mas aí seu problema seria outro :).

#### Um exemplo em C

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bloco.h"

int main(void)
{
    char* teste[] = // uns testes basicos
    {
        "nada",
        "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10",
        "2147483647 -2147483648",
        "21474836472147483648",
        ""
    };

    for (int t = 0; teste[t][0] != 0; t += 1)
    {   // testa uma "linha" do vetor
        char* p    = teste[t];
        char* next = NULL;
        unsigned nc = 0;
        printf("Linha: \"%s\"\n", teste[t]);
        while ((*p != 0))
        {
            long numero = strtol(p, &next, 10);
            if ((numero == LONG_MAX) || (numero == LONG_MIN))
            {
                // e se o cara digitou isso mesmo?
                if (errno == ERANGE)
                {
                    perror("Erro na entrada");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ((next - p) == 0) break;
            p = next;
            printf("%ld  ", numero);
            nc += 1;
        }  // uma coluna
        printf("\nLeu %u campos nessa linha\n\n", nc);
    };  // for
    return 0;
}
```

O programa usa o que tiver em `teste` e roda aquele loop que mostrei.

```
    char* teste[] = // uns testes basicos
    {
        "nada",
        "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10",
        "2147483647 -2147483648",
        "21474836472147483648",
        ""
    };
```

Cada linha do `teste` é como uma linha digitada pelo usuário e assim é mais rápido para testar as hipóteses. O programa para quando der algum erro (*overflow* claro, já que um `int` tem limite) ou achar uma string vazia, que está aí no fim no exemplo. Uma técnica comum de teste.

#### a saída

```
Linha: "nada"

Leu 0 campos nessa linha

Linha: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Leu 10 campos nessa linha

Linha: "2147483647 -2147483648"
2147483647  -2147483648
Leu 2 campos nessa linha

Linha: "21474836472147483648"
Erro na entrada: Result too large

Leu 0 campos nessa linha``none
```

Note que eu deixei um teste completo da condição de erro. E a terceira linha tem o maior e o menor valor possível de ser lido.
A frase em inglês é do sistema dizendo que erro deu na quarta linha, porque o número é BEM grande...

#### Como colocar isso no seu programa

Como você sabe quantas colunas são pode declarar um vetor de `int` e ir colocando os números de cada linha no vetor, usando exatamente o loop que te mostrei acima.

```
    int colunas = 0;
```

Se o programa vai ler o total de colunas basta criar o vetor em seguida...

```
    int* linha = (int*) malloc(colunas * sizeof(int));
```

E pode alocar um para cada linha ou se sabe quantas são pode alocar direto, apenas multiplicando linhas x colunas...

Imagino que sua dúvida não seja nessa parte e vou focar no tópico.

Comment: Muito obrigada! :)